# Change styles when checking checkbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying (with no success) to create a checkbox that changes some style properties of the body when checked, something like this:

```
<script>
  const x = document.getElementById('y');
  if (x.checked == true) { 
    document.body.style.setProperty('property', 'value');
  } else {
    document.body.style.setProperty('property', 'value');
  }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe consider going the pure CSS route: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44804022/691711

Comment: @zero298 Lewis is wanting to change the styles of the `body` element, not the checkbox itself.

Comment: Computers do not think. They do one order after another. If you do `if(...)` you tell the computer to check the `checked` value of `x`, after that is done he will continue doing other things. He won't check again (if you aren't telling him to do so)

Comment: @sean You can still change the style of the `body` by changing its class

Comment: So do did you solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks @nickzoum I was trying to make it work but for some reason it doesn't. The console throws a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' error and I'm looking to understand why.

Comment: Make sure that the id of the element is the same as the id in `document.getElemenyById("{id}")`. If that doesn't work make sure that the script is run after the element gets added

Comment: Also I think any further questions you have regarding the answer should be comments under the answer instead of the question.

Comment: Right, will do. Thanks

Comment: @nickzoum You can't change class of the `body` element with CSS. You need javascript for that.

Comment: @sean Check my answer, the 2nd snippet is what i meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an event listener and run that script inside the listener. What you are doing in your code is setting the color once when the script is run, you haven't told the program to check every time the checkbox is changed.

```js
const checkBox = document.getElementById('y');
checkBox.addEventListener("change", updateBackground);
updateBackground();

function updateBackground() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = checkBox.checked ? "red" : "blue";
}
```

```html
<input id="y" type="checkbox" />
```

You could also just a class instead and change or remove the class name.

```js
const checkBox = document.getElementById('y');
checkBox.addEventListener("change", updateBackground);
updateBackground();

function updateBackground() {
  document.body.className = checkBox.checked ? "" : "blue";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

body.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="y" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Just tested it on a blank page and it works flawlessly. The problem is in my project structure, will check it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to check 2 things. 1. that the id you are getting is correct. 2. that the element exists at the time you are trying to get it. A couple of ways to do that is by adding the script tag at the end. Add an `async` attribute to your `script` tag. Use a `setTimeout` and get the element after a couple of milliseconds. Run the script after everything is rendered using the `DOMContentLoaded` event