# Change parent style with javascript based on checked input

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to change the style of the parent label when the checkbox is checked. I realise this can't feasibly be done with CSS, is this possible with Javascript?

```html
<label id="cont">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Why are you spamming questions!

Comment: Because I was asked to post a new question as there wasn't a CSS solution as per a previous answer - so I asked the equivalent about a javascript solution.

Comment: Have you tried researching ones, This is a very basic question and if you would have even search your own question title, you would have got your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change styles when checking checkbox with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872270/change-styles-when-checking-checkbox-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here's an example:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#cont');
const checkbox = document.querySelector('input');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    container.style.background = 'red'
  } else {
    container.style.background = 'white'
  }
})
```

```html
<label id="cont">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. If you have just a single parent element and checkbox like your code suggests, then it's straightforward.
You can define the new styles you want a class(let's say a class called new-style) inside your stylesheet, then add a listener function inside your js script to trigger when the checkbox is clicked. The listener function will basically insert the class into the parent if it doesn't have it or remove it if it does. Something like this.

```
<script>
  let checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
  checkbox.onclick = function() {
    let parent = document.querySelector('#cont')
  parent.classList.toggle('new-style');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried it this way? You can use css :checked property for this.

```css
input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <input id="name" type="checkbox">
<label for="name" id="cont">
   label
</label>
```

Comment: OP did not ask to change the HTML layout!

Comment: Yeh this would be the ideal solution... but unfortunately I am unable to change the HTML layout